# What's the math to draw a 5dp circle in a Map regardless of zoom level?

Tags: android, google-maps

Working in Java, for Android.
In a `GoogleMap` I want to mimic the current location blue circle, which looks always the same , regardless of what zoom level is used to present the map.

If I want a fixed 5dp circle radius, how do I calculate the `Circle` radius for `GoogleMap` to draw it right?

Comment: use custom view?

Comment: @NabinBhandari No, regular GoogleMap fragment. I want to know in the call to `addCircle()` which radius should I used based on the current zoom level

Comment: If so use a custom view as overlay.

Comment: @NabinBhandari That's definitely one way to go. But I prefer to use `addCircle()` if possible

Comment: Could a custom marker work in this case?

Comment: so you would need to `addCircle` each time the zoom changes (and remove the old circle) - it doesnt pay off

Comment: as @TimBiegeleisen said, I think the best thing is to use a custom marker with some low alpha, flat being true and a little big circular image source, it will remain same on any zoom level.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think your approach might be the right one, because the marker will pan with the map, a Circle has to be redrawn all the time as **pskink** said. Care to post it in Answer format?

Comment: Not certain of this, but if you use a transparent PNG the map may honor the see through portions.

Answer (score 0):

*The answer was given in the comments, so I post it here as answer.
Should be credited to Tim Biengeleisen*

Use a custom marker, with a custom drawable for the circle. The size will remain the same and it will move, zoom, pan with the map automatically